# AD: Domain admin needs elevation

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, uac

I'm trying to change settings on my freshly installed server. I've added it in my domain but I cannot figure out why I keep getting messages like this: "The requested action needs elevation".

The user I'm trying this with is Domain Admin, added in active directory and added to domain admin and administrators group
If I login with domain\administrator + password it works like a charm.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Built-in Administrator accounts on Windows 7 and 2008 R2 by default run always in privileged mode, while the accounts you create by hand and put in Administrator group don't they run as standard user if UAC and Admin Approval is on and you need to authorize privilege elevation by clicking Yes on the Consent UI or running applications by right clicking them and selecting Run as administrator.

If you are running commands from cmd then you need to start it with elevated privileges by right clicking cmd and selecting Run as administrator.